# can't use range inside library chart defined template in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Assume you have a library chart that has a file called _jobs.yaml inside it under the templates directory. Inside the file you have:

```
{{- define "general-lib-chart.jobs.tpl" -}}
{{- $values := .Values -}}
{{- $top := . -}}
{{- range $job := $values.jobs -}}
{{- if $job.enabled -}}

apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ template "general-lib-chart.fullname" $top }}-{{ $job.name }}
---
---
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- define "general-lib-chart.jobs" -}}
{{- template "general-lib-chart.util.merge" (append . "general-lib-chart.jobs.tpl") -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Then you have the chart that calls this library chart that has a file called jobs.yaml in its template folder that has the contents:

```
{{- include "general-lib-chart.jobs" (list . "general-job-service.jobs") -}}
{{- define "general-job-service.jobs" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

then in the values.yaml you have:

```
jobs:

- name: job1
  enabled: true
- name: job2
  enabled: true
- name: job3
  enabled: false
- name: job4
  enabled: true
```

i expect that it should print in the helm template:

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: general-job-service-job1
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: general-job-service-job2
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: general-job-service-job4
```

but instead it prints only:

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: general-job-service-job1
```

whatever i do, it doesnt go through the range, it always does just the first element and if none of the jobs are enabled i get an error as well that says: Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]

I tried printing the value: $values.jobs and i see that it prints the full list of the jobs correctly, but the range function does not work inside the define tpl function in a library chart